# Why is not an error caused by an incorrect html-tag?

Tags: html

In the HTML specification there is a concept called custom elements. There is a definite expression to which the names of these elements should follow. But, however, after opening the editor in the browser, we can safely write elements that do not follow these rules, or simply create a simple page with elements that do not follow this rule. For example, `<redcar> </redcar>`. Why is this allowed and does not cause any errors? After all, if we write something like this: `<~hello> </~hello>` then the opening tag will be treated as text, and the closing tag will be commented out. In any case, you need specific links that will explain this behavior.

> A **valid custom element name** is a sequence of characters name that
>   meets all of the following requirements:
>
> - name must match the *PotentialCustomElementName* production:
>
> *PotentialCustomElementName ::=* `[a-z] (PCENChar)* '-' (PCENChar)*`
>
> *PCENChar ::=* `"-" | "." | [0-9] | "_" | [a-z] | #xB7 | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x203F-#x2040] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]`
>
> This uses the EBNF notation from the XML specification. [XML]
>
> - name must not be any of the following:
>
>   - `annotation-xml`
>   - `color-profile`
>   - `font-face`
>   - `font-face-src`
>   - `font-face-uri`
>   - `font-face-format`
>   - `font-face-name`
>   - `missing-glyph`

Comment: Could you please edit this to make it clearer what exact question you are asking.

Comment: It's very helpful that unknown tags are consumed the way they are. It makes it easy to add new elements of HTML, and browsers that don't yet understand the new elements can just accept them and continue. Because the tags form elements rather than just being discarded, it's possible to add polyfills to replicate the newly expected behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

It's unclear what you'd consider *an error*.

HTML parsing is mainly oriented toward a never throw principle, and will try to convert everything to something valid.

In your specific case, what you created is an [*HTMLUnknownElement*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlunknownelement), and this follows the specs:

> The element interface for an element with name *name* in the HTML
>   namespace is determined as follows:
>
> 1. If *name* is `applet`, `bgsound`, `blink`, `isindex`, `keygen`, `multicol`,
>      `nextid`, or `spacer`, then return HTMLUnknownElement.
> 2. If *name* is `acronym`, `basefont`, `big`, `center`, `nobr`, `noembed`, `noframes`, `plaintext`, `rb`, `rtc`, `strike`, or `tt`, then return
>      HTMLElement.
> 3. If *name* is `listing` or `xmp`, then return HTMLPreElement.
> 4. Otherwise, if this specification defines an interface appropriate for the element type corresponding to the local name
>      *name*, then return that interface.
> 5. If other applicable specifications define an appropriate interface for *name*, then return the interface they define.
> 6. If *name* is a valid custom element name, then return HTMLElement.
> 7. Return HTMLUnknownElement.

---

With `<redcar></redcar>` you gone the whole way until bullet #7.

Comment: Good. What about `<~hello></~hello>`? It will be look as: `"<~hello>"<!--~hello-->`. In your part of specification this is not explain that behaviour.

Comment: @MaximPro this comes from a prior part of the specs, namely the tag name parsing. ~ character is not allowed in HTML tag name (might be in XML thought I don't remember correctly, but anyway not as a starting char). So you don't even enter this algorithm, because it is parsed as text. Now I'm not entirely sure why `</[invalid-char]` gets converted to comment... But this might be somewhere in between SGML and HTML specs.

Comment: So analyzing the source text occurs earlier than evaluating the correct html-tag. I.e at the analysis stage of the source text the incorrect tag will be transformed into some sequence (as we can see in the text and comment). It remains to find these rules, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @MaximPro -The "analysis stage" is called ["Tokenization" and is described in full in the HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tokenization)

Comment: @Alohci Thanks, failed to find the time to find it, so what OP created with their tilde is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-invalid-first-character-of-tag-name

Comment: Well, your link describes the behavior that I brought. But something embarrasses me. There is a note in your link and it says:"While the first code point of a tag name is limited to an ASCII alpha, a wide range of code points (including ASCII digits) is allowed in subsequent positions"And now let's look at the algorithm for constructing the tag (one of the items):"The next few characters of a start tag" - http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags The meaning is that for some reason, it does not specify what the first character should be and what subsequent ones. Why is that?

Comment: @MaximPro check the beginning of the document you linked to: "*This section only applies to documents, authoring tools, and markup generators. In particular, it does not apply to conformance checkers; conformance checkers must use the requirements given in the next section ("parsing HTML documents")."* This document describes **writing** HTML, what you are dealing with is **parsing**. Parsing is more flexible (because of the no throw rule I talked about), and will thus allow some characters out of the ASCII range inside a tag name, (probably because XML does allow it in its syntax).

Comment: Writing in the other hand can be less flexible, e.g from DOM, it will throw. So to make things clearer, at parsing `<f~oo>` will work, but `document.createElement('f~oo')` will throw. And the [rules for writing a tag name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name) in HTML are clear: only ASCII alphanumerics.

Comment: This is understandable, but alphanumeric is [a-z0-9]. Again, the first character can not be a digit, but the subsequent ones can be any characters. I do not quite understand why this rule is for building tags. After all, in fact the <hi#></hi#> tag is correct, but it does not match alphanumeric.

Comment: And: "Tags contain a tag name, giving the element's name. HTML elements all have names that only use ASCII alphanumerics". <0tag></0tag> - will be "<0tag>"<!--0tag--> Need explanation, why?

Comment: I guess it's explained by the 12.2.5.6—12.2.5.8 paragraphs of "Parsing HTML documents" section of the spec, starting at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#tag-open-state. In short, non-alphabetic character after `<` and `</` switches the parser into different modes.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Then for what these rules http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags I do not understand.

Comment: @MaximPro, as Kaiido already said, the "Writing HTML documents" section describes the rules _for authors_ how to write _correct_ HTML documents, while the "Parsing HTML documents" section is about the algorithm how _browsers_ have to parse _any_ HTML documents (including incorrect ones). Some markup examples are considered errors, but browsers can handle those errors in a consistent way.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn what does it mean *rules for authors how to write correct HTML documents*?

Answer (score 0):

Of course errors are caused. You can find them here:

https://validator.w3.org/

If the errors were fatal, i.e. after an error the browser would stop rendering the page, [Google](https://www.google.com/) would be out of business because so few web sites would be on-line that one could easily memorize them.